# Check if Combobox RowSource is Valid

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586641/subform-combobox-rowsource-update-how-update-drop-down-list), but I was hoping there may be a more elegant / simple solution than defining a User-Defined Function.

#### Background

In essence, this is a common question: I need to dynamically modify the RowSource query of a combobox control on an Access form. The twist is that there is a possibility the resulting query  may throw an exception when executed. That is because the source table of the query exists in a different database file which is defined dynamically and may not exist, or even if the file does exist, the desired table or column may not.

Ideally, I would like to be able to catch this problem when the assignment is made, so that the combobox will be disabled and the user cannot invoke the invalid query allowing the end-user to know there is no data available for the field.

For example I would like something like this:

```
Private Sub UpdateComboRows(src as String)
On Error Goto InvalidQueryError
    cmbBox.RowSource = "SELECT [colName] FROM [dBase III;DATABASE=K:\" & src & "].[tblName];"
    ' Something here to invoke RowSource query and throw error
    cmbBox.Enabled = True
Exit Sub

InvalidQueryError:
    cmbBox.RowSource = ""
    cmbBox.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Or something using if-then statements.

#### Question

Are there any 'sleek' approaches to this, or am I stuck with trying to populate a dummy DAO recordset? Is there some way of invoking the Combobox RowSource query besides the Dropdown event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not take a step back and check first that the database exists with Dir, then check that the column exists in a function. Very roughly.

```
Function IsDBOk() As Boolean
   On Error GoTo Err_Trap

   ''The default for boolean is false, so 
   ''IsDBOK=False at this point

   sFile=Dir("K:\" & src)

   If sFile<>"" Then
      Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
      Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT [colName] " _
          & "FROM [dBase III;DATABASE=K:\" _
          & src & "].[tblName];")
      If Not rs.Eof() Then
          ''The selection is only okay if the recordset 
          ''contains records, however, you could return
          ''a different error for each problem
          ''file missing, column missing, empty recordset
          IsDBOk = True
      End If
   End If

   Exit Function

   Err_Trap:
     ''A missing column will give error 3061
     ''IsDBOk is already set to false
End Function
```

Comment: Well since these are DBase files, the dir solution can both verify that database and tables exist. But how about verifying a column is defined in the table? Would I still need to populate a recordset to test it? ... Too bad `CurrentDb.Execute` does not allow SELECT queries.

Comment: With dBase the error is `3061 Too few parameters. Expected 1.`

Comment: Interesting solution, though while implementing I made an interesting discovery: Checking the directory in advance is not really needed since the `CurrentDB.OpenRecordset` call will throw an exception in all three possible error scenarios (3044: bad path, 3011: bad table name, 3061: missing column). **But**, for some reason no error is thrown and records are retrieved if an incorrect table name begins with a valid table name. E.g., if table `[tblName]` exists and I call `SELECT ... FROM [tblName1]`, it runs the query against `[tblName]`. Possibly a bug and worthy of its own Q&A.

Comment: Noted above: this problem only occurs when the valid table name is 8 characters in length - Access will truncate longer names, thus producing this behavior.

Comment: That is interesting. The FileSystemObject can sometimes be a better bet for checking files and directories. You might like to try that.